# C# simple username/password using SQL, user always invalid

Tags: c#, sql, authentication

I am trying to create a simple username/password login using SQL and it always shows up as invalid. Can I please get some feedback?

```
 SqlConnection cn;
        cn = new SqlConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = "Data source=(local); Initial Catalog=INT422Assignment1; Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd;
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT username, pwd FROM myLogin WHERE userNameTB = @username AND passWordTB = @pwd";

        SqlParameter param;
        param = new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.Value = userNameTB;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

        param = new SqlParameter("@pwd", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.Value = passWordTB;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Login"); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid");
        }           
    }
```

It runs, and I put in a breaker right after the commandtext line and so I see that it takes in the input from the textfields, but somehow it doesn't compare it with the username and password in the database.

I thank you for your help.

Cheers,

Essi

Comment: You appear to be storing passwords in plaintext? Please tell me I'm wrong...

Comment: @MitchWheat It's clearly a uni assignment (note the data source,) but yes, this is obviously badness.

Comment: @dlev: I take the view that if you get taught a method, you are likely to continue doing it that way.

Comment: 1. make sure your connection string is correct. 2. cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); should be cmd.ExecuteQuery();

Comment: @MitchWheat I agree; you should write an answer saying so!

Comment: @urlreader I don't find cmd.ExecuteQuery();

And yeah everyone, this is a school assignment. I am using a plaintextbox right now because i was trying to figure out how to do it. For sure I would use a masked textbox for the password.

Comment: @EssiJoon they're not talking about a masked textbox, they're talking about not ***storing*** the password in the database as plain text - think Linkedin... There's many ways to do this, and it will probably end up with you using a hash and a salt. I'd suggest bcrypt, as it's strong and easy to use - see http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/10/bcrypt-dotnet-strong-password-hashing-for-dotnet-and-mono.ashx

Answer (score 2):

If it always shows as invalid, that should be an indication that your query is throwing an exception, since the "invalid" box is shown only if the exception is caught. What are the details of the exception?

If you read the documentation on `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()`, you'll note that in your case, it does nothing useful:

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected
>   by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return
>   value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the
>   number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the
>   return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

So `ExecuteNonQuery()` is not the correct method. I suspect that your exception is being thrown is related to the fact that you've executed a select statement, producing a result set that hasn't been processed, due to using `ExecuteNonQuery()`.

As an aside, I would note that it is considered poor practice to use exceptions for flow-of-control program logic. Exceptions are for...**exceptional** conditions, not ordinary program logic. Further, when catching an exception, one should be as specific as possible.  Otherwise, as you've discovered, you catch exceptions that shouldn't have been caught, which cause other problems.)

I'd do something like this instead:

```
static bool IsAuthenticated( string uid , string pwd )
{
    if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uid) ) throw new ArgumentNullException("uid") ;
    if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pwd) ) throw new ArgumentNullException("pwd") ;

    bool authenticated ;

    using ( SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data source=(local); Initial Catalog=INT422Assignment1; Integrated Security=SSPI;") )
    using ( SqlCommand    cmd = cn.CreateCommand() )
    {

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text ;
        cmd.CommandText = @"
SELECT authenticated = count(*)
FROM myLogin
WHERE userNameTB = @username
AND passWordTB = @pwd"
        ;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@username" , uid ) ;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@pwd"      , pwd ) ;

        cn.Open() ;

        authenticated = ((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0 ? true : false ;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        cn.Close() ;

    }

    return authenticated ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ExecuteScalar()` The executenonquery doesn't return anything. or use SqlDataAdapter and fill in DataTable and see if there are any rows in the DataTable or use ExecuteScalar() to get the first item returned from the database. You need data returned from the database.

On the other hand I would use ASP.NET membership that already has user login/out function built in. I wouldn't build my own login logout webpage.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  //this is for inserting or updating db
            cn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Login"); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid");
        }
```

try this instead using SqlDataReader

```
try{
     SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
     While dr.Read() {

      string password = dr("pwd").ToString();
      string username = dr("username").ToString();
      }  
     }
```

EDIT:

```
 try{
     SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     If dr.HasRows() {
         //Here is your code for good login
      }
     }
```

Comment: I don't think he cares to know what the values are.

Answer (score 0):

A sql query with no results does not throw an exception.  You'll need to get the results and check if they are empty: if (res.MoveNext()).

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe you need the @ symbol in this code.

```
 SqlParameter param;
    param = new SqlParameter("username", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    param.Value = userNameTB;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

The parameter name I believe should just be username same for pwd

Comment: I have had issues with it in older versions of .NET and Visual Studio it may have been corrected in recent versions.